# Why does my C program stop here? Is it creating an infinite loop or something?

Tags: c

Why does my program stop here? Is it creating an infinite loop or something? It doesn't print the highest grade and lowest grade and the general weighted average. It only shows it when I type 'exit.' I use Dev-C++.

```
    int grades[5], i, lGrade, hGrade;
    float sum = 0, GWA;
    
    printf("Enter 5 grades in percentile format within 0-100.");
    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\tGrade No. %d => ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &grades[i]);
        if ((grades[i] < 0) || (grades[i] > 100)) {
            printf("\n\tOnly enter grades from 0 to 100. Please try again.\n\n");
            i -= 1;
        } else {
            continue;
        }        
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &grades[i]);
        sum += grades[i];
    }
    
    GWA = sum / 5;
    
    lGrade = grades[0];
    hGrade = grades[0];
    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (grades[i] < lGrade)
            lGrade = grades[i];
        else if (grades[i] > hGrade)
            hGrade = grades[i];
    }
    
    printf("\nThe highest grade is %d.", hGrade);
    printf("\nThe lowest grade is %d.", lGrade);
    printf("\nThe general weighted average is %0.2f.", GWA);
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Probably `scanf("%d", &grades[i]);` ->`printf("%d\n", grades[i]);`. Closing as typo.

Comment: Also, next time don't post a picture of your output but post your output as properly formatted text. You can copy/paste your output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code asks for the grades twice, it's halting at the `scanf` here:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &grades[i]);
        sum += grades[i];
    }
```

Perhaps you meant `printf()` not `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, the program stops in the second scanf; also I'd like to add that if you just want to print the higher, lower and average values, the second for loop would be unnecesary; and the

```
sum += grades[i];
```

should be inside the else {} clause.